# Specific DateFormat

Tags: jsp, parsing, date

In JSP i am getting date in following format`Wed Jun 03 2015 13:30:40 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"`

How to create a **simple date format** so that i can convert a string into a  **date object**
 `SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("what should be type here");
Date requestStartDate= request.getParameter("startTime");`

i tried `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy")`But it is not working.
[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)  are some of ways for formatting but not this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple Date object with toString() method to print current date and time as follows:

```
<%
   Date date = new Date();
   out.print( "<h2 align=\"center\">" +date.toString()+"</h2>");
%>
```

SimpleDateFormat allows you to start by choosing any user-defined patterns for date-time formatting.

```
<%
   Date dNow = new Date( );
   SimpleDateFormat ft = 
   new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
   out.print( "<h2 align=\"center\">" + ft.format(dNow) + "</h2>");
%>
```

The  tag is used to format dates in a variety of ways

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<html>
<head>
  <title>JSTL fmt:dateNumber Tag</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Number Format:</h3>
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />

<p>Formatted Date (1): <fmt:formatDate type="time" value="${now}" /></p>
<p>Formatted Date (2): <fmt:formatDate type="date" value="${now}" /></p>
<p>Formatted Date (3): <fmt:formatDate type="both" value="${now}" /></p>
<p>Formatted Date (4): <fmt:formatDate type="both" 
        dateStyle="short" timeStyle="short" value="${now}" /></p>
<p>Formatted Date (5): <fmt:formatDate type="both" 
        dateStyle="medium" timeStyle="medium" value="${now}" /></p>
<p>Formatted Date (6): <fmt:formatDate type="both" 
        dateStyle="long" timeStyle="long" 
        value="${now}" /></p>
<p>Formatted Date (7): <fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${now}" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```